# How to hide console in custom action of wix?

Tags: wix

The part of project's code as followers:

```
  <Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
            <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="SetupProjectConsole" />
        </Directory>
    </Directory>
</Fragment>

<Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
  <Component Id="product" Guid="69513FD8-F65A-420F-8FE8-D456890DB457">
       <File Id="Run.bat" Name="Run.bat" Source="Resource\Run.bat"></File>
  </Component>
 </ComponentGroup>
<Property Id="QtExecDeferredExample" Value="&quot;[INSTALLFOLDER]Run.bat&quot;"/>
<CustomAction Id="QtExecDeferredExample" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec"     Execute="deferred" Return="check" Impersonate="no"/>
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="QtExecDeferredExample" After="InstallFiles"></Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
</Fragment>
```

But the log of instlling showing as followers:

```
CAQuietExec:  Error 0x80070002: Command failed to execute.
CAQuietExec:  Error 0x80070002: CAQuietExec Failed
CustomAction QtExecDeferredExample returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
Action ended 11:57:17: InstallFinalize. Return value 3.
```

but if i replace the `[INSTALLFOLDER]` with `C:\Program Files (x86)\SetupProjectConsole\`, the installer does not show any error. How do I deal with this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Can't test so may not help, but I've never assumed a trailing backslash on the directory keys. I'd have used `Value="&quot;[INSTALLFOLDER]\Run.bat&quot;"`

Comment: I have used Value="&quot;[INSTALLFOLDER]\Run.bat&quot;",but the result was also error.Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Batch files are not executables. Batch files are text files that are interpreted by cmd.exe. The QtExec custom action only runs executables so you need to call the interpreter.

Something like the following should work better:

```
<Property Id="QtExecDeferredExample" Value="[SytemFolder]cmd.exe /k &quot;[INSTALLFOLDER]Run.bat&quot;"/>
```

However, calling batch files isn't a hallmark of a robust installation.

Answer (score 0):

What if you try this way:

```
<Property Id="QtExecDeferredExample" Value="&quot;[#Run.bat]&quot;"/>
```

?